# RDF/OWL/SPARQL/Triple Stores/Reasoners and other Semantic Web APIs for C#?

Tags: c#, semantic-web

For those of you working on Semantic Web development, which C# tools do you use for reasoning, parsing, etc.? The idea is to build a central repository of all C# APIs currently available. Sort of like I did [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/654771/algorithms-and-data-structures-that-are-not-mainstream-closed). Please post links, if you can, so I am able to summarize correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A nearly comprehensive list of .net (c# or whatever) semantic web tools could be found at [W3C SemanticWebTools page](http://esw.w3.org/topic/SemanticWebTools#head-d8245ac3b165f69548a586e7eaed613b18706ace) or [AI3 swtools list](http://www.mkbergman.com/?page_id=325)

Answer (score 2):

You could try my Library [dotNetRDF](http://www.dotnetrdf.org) - it is free and open source and provides a state of the spec SPARQL implementation including almost all current draft SPARQL 1.1 features

Answer (score 2):

I found [RDFSharp](http://rdfsharp.codeplex.com) at Codeplex and, for me, it seems promising, with nice ideas and a user-friendly API. It is very young, so it can only mature with the time.

Answer (score 1):

I highly recommend Intelldimensions offerings in this space.

- [Semantics Server](http://www.intellidimension.com/products/semantics-server/)
- [Semantics SDK](http://www.intellidimension.com/products/semantics-sdk/)

Answer (score 1):

for a FOSS product that provides VS.NET extensions, and a full LINQ query provider, consider [linqtordf](http://code.google.com/p/linqtordf)